# ibtool fails with 255 after adding Watch App Target to project

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, ibtool

I would like to add a Watch App to my existing project.
When creating a blank new one the steps described below work as expected however in the given environment I cannot get xcode to compile.

In my project I add a Watch Target by File > New Target > Watch Kit App
When I try to run in Simulator, or on device Build fails 
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

I tried to compile using command line tool as well with no success but more information which I hope help you understanding what is causing the issue

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --flatten NO --errors --warnings --notices --module appname_WatchKit_Extension --minimum-deployment-target 8.4 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/johannes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-avzktnolxsxcysbudfkawtmkeixs/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname\ WatchKit\ App.build/Interface-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/johannes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-avzktnolxsxcysbudfkawtmkeixs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname\ WatchKit\ App.app/Base.lproj /Users/johannes/Documents/Development/projectfoler/appname\ WatchKit\ App/Base.lproj/Interface.storyboard
2015-08-23 22:00:57.776 ibtoold[6319:105962] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-7706/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/IBDocument.m:2439
Details:  Assertion failed: [compiledPackageAsDirectory isDirectory]
Object:   <IBStoryboardDocument: 0x7fb28a019800>
Method:   -fileWrapperOfType:options:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb288c41c60>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001011d9c07 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x00000001011d965f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001011d994e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001011d98b0 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000102050098 -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000010205c4d9 -[IBDocument hybridPackageWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x0000000100fe0ece (in ibtoold)
  7  0x0000000100fddab3 (in ibtoold)
  8  0x0000000100fe0370 (in ibtoold)
  9  0x0000000100fe6233 (in ibtoold)
 10  0x0000000100fe67b0 (in ibtoold)
 11  0x0000000100fe6683 (in ibtoold)
 12  0x0000000100fd566a (in ibtoold)
 13  0x0000000100fe5e2c (in ibtoold)
 14  0x0000000100fe5074 (in ibtoold)
 15  0x00007fff8f4af5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

**Assertion failed: [compiledPackageAsDirectory isDirectory]**

Any help is much appreciated I am out of ideas :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems resolved with latest Xcode Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o).